# Webp images are not seen on smartphones

Tags: wordpress, elementor, smartphone, webp

I have converted all my images to webp with photoshop and I have uploaded them to my Wordpress. However, I cannot see the images from my mobile. I have just added the following code in mu functions.php to allow uploading of the files.

```
function webp_upload_mime($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('mime_types', 'webp_upload_mime');
```

What could I do so that the images are seen from my mobile?
I use the Elementor builder and Ionos hosting.
Thanks!

Comment: Which Wordpress Version are you running?
on WP 5.8+ you don't need you code any more, it's build in core

What get you on your mobile? do you see the alt text?

Comment: I'm got the latest version of wordpress: 5.9.3. 
I see it completely empty in Android: 
https://ibb.co/SmsyTkf

Answer (score 0):

I already discovered the problem, it was the photoshop add that did not work in the correct way.
Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).